# Need explanation for the solution of this limit with cubic root.

Tags: limits, roots

I found this example but don't know how the author solved it, is it a conjugate multiplication. I tried that method but didn't work.

I don't know how it's solved in that way?

Could anyone explain the solution method for this limit example?

[image]

Comment: $$a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
$$$$
Plugin $a^3=y$ and $b^3=1$

Comment: I know, but how did the cubed denominator come from? I know this distribution rule. But, the second step is not clear. First step is ok by multiplying everything by -1.

Comment: $$y-1 = (\sqrt[3]{y})^3-(1)^3$$

Comment: I know, but in the denominator, there's no cubic root at all! Where did it come from afterwards? That's my question.

Comment: What do you mean there is no cubic root. It was there from first step

Comment: I'm sorry I mean numerator! It's not there at all.

Comment: Yes that was made up. But first can you simplify below expression ?$$(\sqrt[3]{y})^3$$

Comment: Yes, it's y. I solved it, I just power 3 the numerator and denominator and that's it, the eBook shows the cubic roots after that which was confusing, and then as you mentioned you apply the cubic distribution rule. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would Substitute $$\sqrt[3]{y}=a$$ then you will get
$$\frac{1-a^3}{1-a}=-\frac{\left( a-1 \right)  \left( {a}^{2}+a+1 \right)}{1-a}$$
and this is $$a^2+a+1$$ and since $$y$$ tends to $1$ the variable $a$ must tends to one, and the searched Limit is $3$

Comment: But, the cubic root shouldn't be there after applying this cubic rule. I think there's a mistake with the solution in the eBook I got the it from.

Comment: can you send me a link to the eBook?

Comment: It's an Arabic version for our technical diploma program. https://cdd.tvtc.gov.sa/sites/default/files/document/_tkhssy114ryd.pdf, question at beginning of page 16.

Comment: but i can not read this language, sorry

Comment: respect, who can read this! it is the same as my trick, $3$ is the right result.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help.

Comment: can you teach me this language?

Comment: wish you a nice evenening and all the best for your Country!

Comment: Really? You want to learn Arabic?

Comment: why not, i'm very interested

Comment: Why you want to learn Arabic? Do you want to visit the Arabic countries? There are people who learnt this language but I think they love the Arabic culture at first. Because I think you need a huge motivation to learn a new language.

Comment: Well, I can speak with you on Snapchat and try to introduce you to good Arabic communities whilst I'm actually not so concentrating on Arabic communities. I do most of my work with English websites.

Comment: in the University of Halle-Wittenberg Germany we had Arabic students there and i was the lecturer

Comment: You are German! WOW I love Germany such an intelligent people and beautiful country. My snapchat is r1s8k, it's my honor to talk with a doctor I'm an electronics trainer at a technical college and trying my best to be good in electronics.

Comment: it is very nice to meet you!